# How to Pass Array Object to another activity?

Tags: android

I am looking for some help with a tutorial I have been working on. I am trying to pass an object when I click on a list item from one activity to another using an Intent. I have posted some of the tutorial code I have been using below but can't seem to get it to work.

My Main Activity code is below:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_HEROES_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i =0; i<array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            Hero hero = obj.getString("name"));

                            heroList.add(hero);
                        }

                        adapter = new HeroAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

And from my Adapter this is the code I have been using this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Hero hero = heroList.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(hero.getName());

    holder.textViewName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HeroDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_HERO_ID, hero.getName());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The intent is listed but it is not carrying the data into my new activity. I just want to take

```
 hero.getName()
```

at the position it was clicked on in the itemlist and open up a new activity, and in the new activity set it to a TextView. This is part of code I have used on the new activity, but it wont post anything into the TextView.

```
TextView textViewName

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hero_detail);


    textViewname = (textView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent == null)
        return;

    int id = intent.getIntExtra(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_ID, -1);
    err.setText(id);
```

For instance I click on spiderman set in the list which is at position 3, and in the new activity the textView will load with Spiderman listed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass objects using `serializable` or `parcelable` interfaces but if you just want the name of your hero you should pass it as `string` in your intent. Now you're passing an `id`. You can totally do that. If it's `int` you should set it correctly to `textview`

```
err.setText(String.valueOf(id));
```

That's why it's not working now.

Or just pass it as `string` right from the beginning

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HeroDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY_HERO_NAME, hero.getName());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And then retrieve it

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent == null)
        return;

    String heroName = intent.getStingExtra(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_NAME);
    err.setText(heroName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
int id = -1;
if(getIntent().hasExtra(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_ID)){
    id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_ID);
}
err.setText("" + id);
```

If you need send the hero name then:

> In your adapter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HeroDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY_HERO_ID, hero.getName());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

> In your activity:

```
String heroName = "";
if(getIntent().hasExtra(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_ID)){
    heroName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(HeroAdapter.KEY_HERO_ID);
}
err.setText(heroName);
```